# Splitting string by more empty lines

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to make a DF from the data that is raw text. It's separated using only empty lines, from 1 to more empty lines between elements.

So the main goal is to split it, or insert commas, so I can pass it to DF, for further modifications.

```
#input

    12386 GP ACCT @ GURDON AR TB    S   Delivery Location   DPQ      Y         4,350       4,350       1,621         2,729    Delivery           NO  (b)


# output
    ['12386', 'GP ACCT @ GURDON AR TB', 'S', 'Delivery Location', 'DPQ', 'Y', '4,350', '4,350', '1,621', '2,729', 'Delivery', 'NO  (b)']
```

The main trouble I am having that the text is having multiple empty lines, so using `.split()`, will split on every empty line.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem using `re.split()` with `\s+ {2,}`

Comment: But it does not yield the expected output.

Comment: Well, the output, is pretty much similar to what I wanted, but the only downside is that the first two elements are combined into one string. So I've just added a few more logic after that to fix that, but overall it's the best solution I could find without complicating too much